# Ingress nginx enable Cors headers only on Specific Hosts

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an Ingress configuration, I want to enable cors headers on some specific hosts!

I set the annotation in the ingress to

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
```

This works but, also will set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in some other hosts
For example:

```
curl 'https://example.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' --compressed -H 'Origin: https://hacker.org' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -v
```

The result would be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: hacker.org`
which is not what I expect!

I want to configure the ingress in a way that it sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only on some specific hosts!

I tried this annotation!

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
         if ($http_origin ~*  'https://example.com') {
              more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
         }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
```

But does not work!

I want the ingress configured to set Cors headers only on some specific hosts!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you enabled cors `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"` and with that the default for `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin` came into play which is `*`.
Simply configure it with the appropriate annotation like so:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://origin-site.com"
```

More information can be found here:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors